# Nvidia not able to turn off or switch to Intel on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, nvidia-optimus

I have Nvidia 5200m and I'm using the additional driver from Nvidia. I want to only use Intel GPU and turn off Nvidia. I try to do this with `prime-select intel` and it works, but when the system reboots I get a black screen with only the mouse cursor.

I have no option to select from BIOS, except to turn off or on Nvidia optimus. Nvidia optimus needs to be off in BIOS for the additional driver to work (it's off now).

My laptop is a Dell-Latitude e6430.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install driver

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-390
   ```
2. Run this command

   ```
   sudo prime-select intel
   ```
3. Delete `xorg.conf` generated by nvidia driver installation:

   ```
   rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```
4. Edit GRUB configuration file

   ```
   sudo vim  /etc/default/grub
   ```

   Replace `nouveau.runpm=0` with `nouveau.runpm=1` in the line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`. Save and exit.
5. Write the changes to GRUB:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
6. Enable Nvidia optimus from BIOS

Comment: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings we want to delete it to allow intel get work without problems because it's have only NVIDIA Device.